# fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslconf.h'

Tags: openssl

I am compiling OpenSSL with Visual Studio 2012 on windows 10. I have installed below :

Visual Studio 2012
strawberry-perl-5.38.0.1
openssl-1.1.1w

I am getting below error :

..\openssl-1.1.1w\e_os.h(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'openssl/opensslconf.h': No such file or directory

Note : opensslconf.h file is generated/created in "openssl-1.1.1w\include\openssl\opensslconf.h"
path.

Please help to resolve issue.